# Cannot Render a React Class Component that has Inheritance to Another Component. Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-component

Sorry I haven't worked with class components in forever and this is the first time I am trying to inherit from another component. I am currently trying to extend a class component from a node module I use so I can add more functionality but when I render the extended class I get the error
`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports`

Here is the node module's component that I am trying to extend:

```
var PlacesAutocomplete = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(PlacesAutocomplete, _React$Component);

  function PlacesAutocomplete(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, PlacesAutocomplete);

...
// the function I want to extend to add more key down events
_this.handleInputKeyDown = function (event) {
      /* eslint-disable indent */
      switch (event.key) {
        case 'Enter':
          event.preventDefault();
          _this.handleEnterKey();
          break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent the cursor from moving
          _this.handleDownKey();
          break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent the cursor from moving
          _this.handleUpKey();
          break;
        case 'Escape':
          _this.clearSuggestions();
          break;
      }
      /* eslint-enable indent */
    };

...
 _createClass(PlacesAutocomplete, [{
    key: 'componentDidMount',
...
 return PlacesAutocomplete;
}(_react2.default.Component);
```

Is it because the node module builds the component into this very weird function class format? If so how do I get the node module to be like the normal class component format that is used in the github source code for the React-Places-Autocomplete node module?

Here is my class where I am trying to extend the handleInputKeyDown function:

```
import PlacesAutocomplete from 'react-places-autocomplete';

export default class ExtendedPlacesAutocomplete extends PlacesAutocomplete {
    handleInputKeyDown = (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
            // new key event switch logic
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to call the super constructor and render in the class incase that was the issue but that did not resolve it. I am exporting the default class so I have no clue why I am receiving the error message.

Here is code that imports it and tries to render the class component:

```
import ExtendedPlacesAutocomplete from './ExtendedPlacesAutocomplete';
...
return(
...
<ExtendedPlacesAutocomplete
                    value={input.value}
                    onChange={address => input.onChange(address)}
                    options={options}
                    classNames={cssClasses}
                    autocompleteItem={AutocompleteItem}
                    onSelect={handleSelect}
                >
                    {renderFunc}
                </ExtendedPlacesAutocomplete>
...
);
```

Note: this component is a being wrapped and rendered in a redux form field so that may be causing issue but I doubt that.
Also If I console log the ExtendPlacesAutoComplete class I get an empty object {}

Sorry for being completely new this kind of component and thank you for all the help in advance

Comment: you need to show the actual code... not the transpiled code.  we need a fully reproducible example... otherwise how can we debug it?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro are you saying that it does not matter if the code is transpiled, it still should be able to be extended? If so then I will update the code snipped in the question to include the class from the github source code instead of transpiled stuff in my node modules folder